# How to show navigation menu on click (and not hover) from parent menu

Tags: html, menu, navigation

How to display the navigation menus drop down when on **parent menu click** (and not when hover over the parent menu) 
I am using bootstrap navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap drop downs already collapse on click by default. see
[bootstrap dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp).
But if you want them to collapse on hover. Below is the jQuery code to do just that :-

```
$(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).removeClass('open');       
});
```